# multiple column images that completely fill the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wish to have lots of clickable images to cover the width of the browser window. So no space either side. Ideally id like individual images to stay at 180x180px in size, but if its easier they can change size, according to the browser window. Just need to fill the space. At the moment if i make the containing div bigger than the body, it creates a space overflow on the right. If that makes sense.

This is my code:-
http://jsfiddle.net/ZPTBB/

This is how i would like it to look:-
http://www.karen.hunter.myzen.co.uk/pinewood/image_so.jpg

Perhaps it needs query????

Thank you for your help in advance.

My code:-

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title>Untitled Document</title>
            <style>
            /* Editable Multiple Image Area */
            .image-container {width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; height:360px; overflow:hidden;}
            .image{position:relative;float:left;width:188px;height:188px; margin:0; padding:0;}
            .image img {position:absolute;z-index:1;left:0;top:0;}
            .image:hover div {display:block!important; }
            .image img:hover div {display:none;position:absolute;z-index:2; width:100%; height:100%; background:red;}
            .hoverimg {display:none;position:absolute;z-index:2; width:100%; height:100%; background:red;}
            </style>
            </head>

            <body>
            <!-- IMAGE CONTAINER -->
                  <div class="image-container">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>


                       <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/188x188" />
                            <div class="hoverimg"><a href="success.html"><img src="_includes/img/global/image.jpg" width="188" height="188" /></a></div>
                        </div>
                  </div><!-- IMAGE CONTAINER -->
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/?icn=tabz - Are you looking for something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a few extra containers that can contain the overflowing images:

```
.image-container {
    width:100%; 
    height:360px; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
.image-container-overflow {
    width: 100%; 
    padding-right:187px; /* assuming 188px width for image */
    height: 360px; 
    position: relative;
}
.image-container-actual {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 360px; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0
}
```

The first takes 100% + 187px via padding, the next takes up this total by absolute positioning

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/pq26W/

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you so much. How would i make them responsive so they scale with browser?

Comment: You can use a responsive trick with padding and box-sizing to create a responsive container. 

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/xNdzz/1/